# equal(=). Why for primitive widening is works but for wrapper not?

Tags: java, type-conversion, wrapper, primitive, boxing

I noticed surprising behaviour

### code 1:

```
double dPrimitive = 1; //valid line of code
```

It is valid string and code compiles good - expected result for me.

### code 2:

```
Double dWrapper = 1 ; // invalid line of code
```

It is INvalid string and code doesn't compile - UNexpected result for me.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Double
```

Why for primitive widening is works bit for wrapper - not ?

Comment: what is the mean of valid string here `double dPrimitive = 1; //valid string`

Comment: I try cast int to Double - not vice-versa

Comment: @Braj OP mean the value :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ where is string?

Comment: I think by "string" OP means "line of code"

Comment: @Braj I think it's `1` as per OP. (*My understanding*).

Comment: Edited topic according the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision:

`widening -> boxing`   - invalid conversion chain

`boxing -> wideining`   - valid conversion chain

this code:

```
 Object  d=1;
 System.out.println(d.getClass());
```

returns

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

First case: In case of primitives [`primitive widening`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) happening  and `int` to `double` there.

Second case : You need boxing and unboxing there and the RHS should be an exact primitive to the corresponding Wrapper.

So you need to tell the compiler that the value in right side is a **double**.

```
Double dWrapper = 1D ; //valid now
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Double dWrapper = 1 ; // invalid
```

Widening doesn't work in this example, because your statement needs both widening (from `int` to `double`) and then auto-boxing (`double` to `Double`) for it to be a legal assignment. Java will automatically do one or the other for you, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Because to allow the latter to work **you'd need first a widening operation, then a box operation**. But widening is not defined for objects, just for primitives.

The only way to allow it to work would be first to widen the primitive type, something like `int -> double -> Double` but this would require the compiler to force a widen just because it realizes that the result is assigned to a `Double` specific object, just to box if afterwards, which wouldn't make so much sense.